# Change <Route> component for "/" when logged in (React)

Tags: reactjs, express

The routing for this web app I'm building will render either the Home or Index component depending on whether or not there is a user logged in. Here is my routing right now.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      // <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} /> When logged in
      <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Index} />
      <Route path="/account/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/account/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Right now I am logging/registering users in and saving the user's ID as a session variable in express. So as long as that variable is present I should be able to check if user is "loggedIn".

Can this be done conditionally within the switch like..

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      if(loggedIn) { 
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} /> 
      } else { 
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Index} /> 
      }
      <Route path="/account/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/account/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

or is there a better practice for handling Routing instances like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a conditional statement in your `Switch`. I would opt for using a ternary in the `component` prop instead of two separate Routes:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={loggedIn ? Home : Index} />
      <Route path="/account/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/account/signup" component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Also, when a prop's value is `true`, you can omit passing `{true}` and React will default it to `true`.

```
exact={true} 
exact
```

Comment: Thank you! that was so simple i can't believe it didn't come to mind..and thanks for the tip, good to know

Answer (score 0):

If you like "if"-"else" construction you can use it:

```
  {(() => {
    if (false) {
      return <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 
    }
    return <Route path="/" exact component={Index} />
  })()}
```

But it's better to using a ternary.